# why is this integer result not as expected?

Tags: java, math

I have 7 integers, and one calculation. Calculating `maximumY` should equal `-3940` but instead produces `1724869434`.

Why is this?

```
in1 = 1000;
in2 = 1000;
in3 = 100;
in4 = 100;
in5 = 100;
in6 = 1000;
in7 = 100;
duration / 1000 = 24;
frequency1 / 1000 = 5
frequency2 / 1000 = 5
frequency3 / 1000 = 10
frequency4 / 1000 = 24
frequency5 / 1000 = 2
frequency6 / 1000 = 2
frequency7 / 1000 = 4

int cal1 = in1 + (in1 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency6 / 1000));
int cal2 = in1 + (in2 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency7 / 1000));
int cal3 = out1 +(out1 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency1 / 1000));
int cal4 = out2 +(out2 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency2 / 1000));
int cal5 = out3 +(out3 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency3 / 1000));
int cal6 = out4 +(out4 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency4 / 1000));
int cal7 = out5 +(out5 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency5 / 1000));

maximumY = (cal1) + (cal2) - (cal3) - (cal4) - (cal5) - (cal6) - (cal7);
```

Comment: warning! overflow error. Consider using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), not int for this.

Comment: And wouldn't all those thousands simply cancel each other out? In other words, isn't `(duration / 1000) / (frequency5 / 1000)` the same as `duration  / frequency5`?

Comment: line one has `in1` twice, line 2 has `in1` and `in2`, and the other lines have `out*` which you're not showing...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not necessarily: `(1500 / 1000) / (1999 / 1000) == 1/1 == 1 != 1500/1999 == 0`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You are right of course -- I forgot about int division -- a terrible newbie mistake!

Comment: Sorry int 3 onwards is out1 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `long` provided you want to perform integer arithmetic.

Otherwise I would use double with appropriate rounding, or BigDecimal.

You could simplify your code

```
long cal6 = out4 +(out4 * (duration / 1000) / (frequency4 / 1000));
```

is

```
long cal6 = out4 +(out4 * 24 / (24));
```

or

```
long cal6 = out4 * 2;
```

Comment: All data is taken from textfields so are subject to change.